# populating dropdown using php and mysql where clause not working

Tags: php, dropdown

im trying a basic thing but there is some problem with my query, Im trying to populate names in a dropdown where status = Arrived, however the query doesn't work with where clause, neither giving any syntax error. Here is my code:

```
$sql= mysqli_query($con,"Select name from reservations where status='Arrived'"); 
$result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
echo "<select name=\"name\">"; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) 
{        
echo "<option value='".$row['name']."'>".$row['name']."</option>"; 
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: Not working in what way? No options are populated? Here's a thorough [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/4205384) on debugging `mysqli` related problems.

Comment: I mean when I put "where" in the query, it doesn't populate the values in drop down, else it does show all the names in the list. But since I want only those names having specific status, that's why I have to use "where " clause.Thanks

Comment: And if you run this query directly on your database, does it return any records?

Comment: Yes,it does, when i run this directly on my database.

Comment: If `mysqli` is showing no errors, then something in your question is misrepresented. Are you sure you're running an *identical* query on your db? Is `'Arrival'` really hardcoded?

Comment: 'Arrived' is hard coded, even if i run the query on db with any other status which exists in db, it shows results, but not on my page, it simply shows empty drop down.

Comment: It might be a problem with case. Have you tried with `'arrived'`?

Comment: but in db, value exists with captial A.

Comment: Then I am at a loss. Without a reproducible example, I have no other ideas why this would fail.

Comment: I figured out the issue, basically the row entry against the Arrived status wasn't complete, and there was only one value with this status, hence it wasn't picking anything in drop down, when i checked query with other status, it worked, so it gave me the hint that my query is correct, only issue was with the entries against Arrived status, thanks anyway.